# Woocommerce Subscriptions Email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I need advice on the WooCommerce Subscription plugin. This means that when someone buys a package, they will receive an email with an invoice and information. This email contains the date of the next payment. Would anyone know how to remove it from the email?

[image]

Thank you

I tried to remove it with the function but it doesn't work very well